# SQL statement to query records above a record

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, window-functions, lag

I have a database with 6 million records that was extracted from a PDF accounting document.

In the database, I have a record in column A whose value is:  "Employee Name". And an incrementing index in column B numbered from one to 6 million.

The record ABOVE the value "Employee Name" is SOMETIMES the name of the employee, with a number.

Sometimes it is a null, and sometimes it is a number. In either case, the employee name is listed in the record above that one.

Example:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| "John Smith 12345" | 19 |
| "Employee Name" | 20 |
| "Something Else" | 21 |
| "Something Else" | 22 |
| "Jane Smith 56789" | 23 |
| "null" | 24 |
| "Employee Name" | 25 |
| "Something Else" | 26 |
| "Something Else" | 27 |
| "Jacob John Smith Jr." | 28 |
| "98765" | 29 |
| "Employee Name" | 30 |
| "Something Else" | 31 |

I need to get the name of the employee.  Filtering out the number might be nice bonus, but for now I am happy with just getting the name at least.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT A 
FROM PAYROLL_RECORDS
WHERE B IN (SELECT (B - 1) FROM PAYROLL_RECORDS 
            WHERE A = 'Employee Name') 
ORDER BY A;
```

This would work perfectly if the name was always the row on top of it.

I would need a `SELECT` statement perhaps that grabs the TWO rows on top, AND checks if it has CHARACTERS in the A column (instead of a number or a NULL).

I need a list of all distinct employee names, in a complete scan of all 6 million records.

Ideas?

Comment: These are all very excellent answers.  However please note also that I am using "Oracle Database 10g Express Edition Release 10.2.0.1.0 - Product".  So far, none of them are working for my version.

Answer (score 0):

Select both rows and discard wrong ones with regex

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT A FROM PAYROLL_RECORDS
WHERE
   (B IN (SELECT (B - 1) FROM PAYROLL_RECORDS WHERE A = 'Employee Name') OR
    B IN (SELECT (B - 2) FROM PAYROLL_RECORDS WHERE A = 'Employee Name')) AND
   NOT regexp_like(A, '^(\d+|null)$') 
ORDER BY A;
```

The success also dpends on what is in "Something Else". You might also have to discard additional values in the regex.

Comment: So I would need to scan all the records twice to get two B values.  Have I read that correctly?

Comment: No, the WHERE clause already selects two rows B - 1 and B - 2.

Comment: But isn't it getting the B from two other SELECT queries inside the WHERE?  Would it run twice inside the WHERE, then once more on the resulting WHERE query?

Comment: Yes, but you would have to run this whole query just once and Oracle query optimizer might do it better than running 3 queries. But if this does not work, it would probably better to do this with an algorithm in a common programming language.

Comment: Is there a way to use a WITH to get the values of B instead, perhaps?  Then use arithmetic on the values of the WITH table?

Comment: As often in SQL, there are a lot of different possible solutions. But to know which one is the fastest, you must do benchmarks. The outcome not only depends on the query but also on a lot of other factors like the size of the table, the available indexes, the statistical distribution of the index values, the hardware and more. What is appropriate in this case is to use [window functions](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/mysql-8.0-en/window-functions-usage.html).

Answer (score 0):

No join or subquery is needed. With the help of where clause you can remove null and numeric values from A column then `lag()over()` window function will help you to get the preceding value of every 'Employee Name'. First row will always be `null`

Query:

```
select distinct case when A='Employee Name' then lag(regexp_replace(A, '[0-9]', ''))over(order by B) end as A from PAYROLL_RECORDS 
  where A is not null and VALIDATE_CONVERSION(A AS NUMBER) <> 1
```

Output:

| A |
| --- |
| *null* |
| John Smith |
| Jane Smith |
| Jacob John Smith Jr. |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/KZD8lw0a)

If you wanna remove the first row with null value then :

Query:

```
select A from
(select distinct case when A='Employee Name' then lag(regexp_replace(A, '[0-9]', ''))over(order by B) end as A from PAYROLL_RECORDS 
  where A is not null and VALIDATE_CONVERSION(A AS NUMBER) <> 1 )
 t where A is not null
```

Outpu:

| A |
| --- |
| John Smith |
| Jane Smith |
| Jacob John Smith Jr. |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/fyonTxm0)

In oracle 10g `validate_conversion()` is not available. Instead you can user `REGEXP_LIKE()`

Query:

```
select A from
(select distinct case when A='Employee Name' then lag(regexp_replace(A, '[0-9]', ''))over(order by B) end as A from PAYROLL_RECORDS 
  where A is not null and not REGEXP_LIKE(A, '^[[:digit:]]+$'))
 t where A is not null
```

Output:

| A |
| --- |
| John Smith |
| Jane Smith |
| Jacob John Smith Jr. |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/V-Q9QIY2)

Comment: I get an error...  "ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis 00907. 00000 -  "missing right 
 parenthesis" *Cause:    *Action: Error at Line: 3 Column: 49"  It seems to be hung up on THEN LAG.  I am using Oracle Free Edition, version 10 if that helps.

Comment: It shouldn't. Have you made any changes? Please check the fiddle link.

Comment: I am using "oracle Database 10g Express Edition Release 10.2.0.1.0 - Product"  The statement works perfectly in the newer versions.  Try dropping the version in the Fiddle, and you will get the same error.

Comment: @Stephen-Developer I have added the answer for oracle 10g.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the values of two row WITH the window function `LEAD`

```
WITH CTE AS
(SELECT
  "A",
  LEAD("A") OVER(ORDER BY "B") row1
  ,
  LEAD("A",2) OVER(ORDER BY "B") row2
  FROM 
PAYROLL_RECORDS)
SELECT "A" FROM CTE 
  WHERE (row1 = 'Employee Name' OR row2 = 'Employee Name') 
  AND (NOT REGEXP_LIKE("A", '^[[:digit:]]+$'))
```

| A |
| --- |
| John Smith 12345" |
| Jane Smith 56789 |
| Jacob John Smith Jr. |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/OdaN1nU7)

IF you have spaces you can `TRIM` A

```
WITH CTE AS
(SELECT
  "A",
  LEAD(TRIM("A")) OVER(ORDER BY "B") row1
  ,
  LEAD(TRIM("A"),2) OVER(ORDER BY "B") row2
  FROM 
PAYROLL_RECORDS)
SELECT "A" FROM CTE 
  WHERE (row1 LIKE  'Employee Name' OR row2 LIKE 'Employee Name') 
  AND (NOT REGEXP_LIKE("A", '^[[:digit:]]+$'))
```

| A |
| --- |
| John Smith 12345" |
| Jane Smith 56789 |
| Jacob John Smith Jr. |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/fcUbeGH-)

Comment: Wow...  very interesting idea.  I'm still trying to make it work on my system, but I ran the sub-query and like the ingenuity of it.  I'm keeping this in mind.  I'm still trying to figure why it came back blank, and will let you know.

Comment: I think I figured it out.  I used a LIKE instead of = in the WHERE and it was able to get a response.  I'm not sure, but I think there may be some blank spaces in the Employee Name.

Comment: then trim the columns like in the second

Comment: Bingo!  Looks like that is working.  I got come oddball data too, but out of 6 million records, I figured that would happen and I think I can work that out from here.  Thank you.

Comment: Hey!  We forgot the DISTINCT...  LOL!

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want the "previous" non-null and non-numeric value of each occurrence of string `'Employee Name'` in the column.

I would recommend `lag` with a conditional expression and the `ignore nulls` option:

```
select distinct employee_name
from (
    select p.*,
        lag(case when not regexp_like(a, '^\d+$') then a end)
            ignore nulls 
            over(order by b) employee_name
    from payroll_records p
) p
where a = 'Employee Name'
```

The trick is to have the expression within `lag()` turn all-digits values to `null`s, so that `ignore null`s option skips them when looking up the actual employee name.

Note that:

- this performs a single table scan
- this works regardless of how many rows need to be skipped

**[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/3Tl27mx8)** - in nbk's fiddle (thanks nbk).

Comment: This works perfectly in fiddle.  For some reason I get the error, "missing window specification for this function" while running it on the Oracle Express SQL Developer though.  Any idea why?

Comment: Which version of Oracle are you running @Stephen-Developer? `select * from V$VERSION;`

Comment: Oracle Database 10g Express Edition Release 10.2.0.1.0 - Product

Comment: That's an old version. I *think* that `ignore nulls` was supported already in 10g - but I can't test in the fiddlde (where the oldest available version is 11g). Maybe you can try to move the option within the parentheses, like `lag(case ... end ignore nulls) over(...)`.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/ZWrKnS6P

Comment: I'm thinking of trying to upgrade the database.  Not sure if it will cause issues though.

Comment: Did you try the other syntax (from [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76212593/sql-statement-to-query-records-above-a-record/76212934?noredirect=1#comment134400504_76212934), and the corresponding fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Remove any null values and digits from the values using first CTE, then mark "Employee Name" as 1 and the other values as 0.

A second CTE to retrieve the preceding rows for each 'Employee Name' row.

```
WITH CTE AS (
   SELECT A, B, CASE WHEN A = 'Employee Name' then 1 else 0 end as flaged
   FROM PAYROLL_RECORDS
   WHERE A is not null AND (NOT REGEXP_LIKE("A", '^[[:digit:]]+$'))
),
CTE2 AS (
  SELECT A, B, flaged, lead(flaged) over (order by B) as NameRank
  FROM CTE
)
select A
from CTE2
where NameRank = 1
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/vG84qBgo)